# NullPointerException when accessing static variable in another class in Java

Tags: java

I have trying to access a static variable of class A in class B, however I am getting NullPointerException. The code is :

```
public class OutgoingMessage {
    public static SMPPSession session;
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
         session = new SMPPSession();

    }
  }
```

And

```
public class SendSMS {
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
      if(OutgoingMessage.session.getSessionState().toString().equals("Connected"))//Line 44 
        {
        }
    } 
}
```

The error reads

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at SendSMS.main(SendSMS.java:44)
```

Any idea what am I missing ?

Thanks

Satya

Answer (score 6):

Sure - you're using `OutgoingMessage.session`, which will be null unless you've *also* run `OutgoingMessage.main`. It's not like `main` methods get invoked automatically everywhere - that's just the entry point for the application.

I suggest that instead of changing this to use a static initializer or something like that, you try to work to *avoid* static variables.

Why would it make sense for `OutgoingMessage` to have a static `session` variable? I'd expect the two to work together, not one be composed of the other... for example, I could imagine:

```
SMPPSession session = new SMPPSession();
session.send(outgoingMessage);
```

or even:

```
SMPPSession session = new SMPPSession();
outgoingMessage.sendInSession(session);
```

Answer (score 2):

`OutgoingMessage.session` is `null` at the point where you are calling

```
if(OutgoingMessage.session.getSessionState()
```

Which results in `NullPointerException`.

Make sure `OutgoingMessage` class `main` method is executed before making  `if(OutgoingMessage.session.getSessionState()`

Unless you use OutgoingMessage as main class, it doesn't make sense to define main method there, which confuses more.

Comment: since is public, it could be defined but not for certain, and in practice is not the case.

Comment: @ValentinRuano: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: I guess I was pedantic on the fact that being a public member a third party code could initialise it... but looking back at the stack trace that is rather unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `OutgoingMessage.main(args);` before:

```
if(OutgoingMessage.session.getSessionState().toString().equals("Connected")) //Line 44 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a static getter method in OutgoingMessage, and you only need one main method.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you use `OutgoingMessage.session` it is not yet initialized. To correctly initialize it do:

```
public class OutgoingMessage {
    public static SMPPSession session = new SMPPSession();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized your static variable.. That's why..

Actually you have done that in `main()`, but that will really not affect your output.. As your main will never be run.. You can initialize it at the place of declaration only..

```
public static SMPPSession session = new SMPPSession();
```

Before main method..
But it doesn't make sense to have it as static variable..

You should declare it as instance variable and initialize it for each instance you create using a `Constructor`..